# Angular UI Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't close because parent stops propagation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown, event-propagation

I got a wrapper that stops event propagation because of other things happening in and with that wrapper. In that wrapper I got several directives with UI Bootstrap dropdowns.

The problem is, that these dropdowns doesn't close on any click. Only by clicking another dropdown.

It seems that UI Bootstrap Dropdown watches click on body or something to close all dropdowns.

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; background:grey;">
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
  <button id="split-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bHHrpipM4MlxLNfOE2pt?p=preview

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js#L13) the event handler for closing of dropdown element is getting attached to `window.document` element:

```
$document.on('click', closeDropdown);
```

but at the same time `$event.stopPropagation()` method prevents `click` event from being executed.

If you want dropdown to trigger events in this scenario then you could bind `click` event to dropdown that basically triggers `document` element `click` event:

```
$scope.dropDownClick = function($event) {
    angular.element(document).triggerHandler('click');
};
```

Dropdown element

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="dropDownClick($event)" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
   ...
</ul>
```

Forked [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/d9qQRaoiiPfjkLcfjq9D?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround you could use is shown at this working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qVabGqJDM4VOIixfNhau?p=preview).

You need to stop wrapper's propagation and use a variable to toggle dropdown's `is-open` attribute.